# Preventing multiple functions if something is currently selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a navigation menu that upon hovering (using the hoverIntent plugin and tweenmax to animate) replaces a div with the relevant background image. I have this all working fine, but what i'm stumped with is how to prevent the action being repeated on the element that is currently selected. So for example if you hover over the first and then hover off it I don't want the action to be repeated once you hover over that one again because it is already selected. Attached is the link my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/olichalmers/5csofnhz/1/

```
var homeNav = function () {
    var tgt = $(this);

    $("#homeImageNav a ").hoverIntent({
        over: homeNavOver,
        out: homeNavOff,
        interval: 0
    });

    function homeNavOver() {

        var tgt = $(this);
        var bgHold = $("#bgHolder");
        var bg = tgt.attr('data-bg');

        if (!tgt.hasClass('current')) {
            TweenMax.set($("#bgHolder"), {
                opacity: 0,
                background: bg,
                scale: 1.1
            });
            TweenMax.to(bgHold, 1.5, {
                opacity: 1,
                scale: 1,
            });
        }
        //tgt.addClass('current');
    }

    function homeNavOff() {
        //if (tgt.hasClass('current')) {
        //tgt.removeClass('current');
        //}
    }
};
```

And here is the homeNav function.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5csofnhz/4/)?

Comment: In your `homeNavOver` function, you check `if (!tgt.hasClass('current'))` before you set the background. But you've commented out `tgt.addClass('current');` so it'll never be `.current`. In other words, you can't tell whether it's selected or not and act accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make changes in your function - homeNavOff like this:

```
function homeNavOff() {
    $('#homeImageNav a').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
}
```

See it in action on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5csofnhz/3/)

Comment: Incredible it was such a simple solution. You can tell i'm not the sharpest javascript dev! Thanks Manik.

Comment: Oliver, every moment we learn something new, I am glad I helped you too.

Comment: Manik - can you explain how this works because as far as i'm aware $(this) in this case is the same as $('#homeImageNav a') , correct? Shouldn't they just cancel each other out? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Oliver - $(this) will have the reference of only the element on which the event was raised i.e. the only the single $('#homeImageNav a') anchor element on which the mouse was hovered but not any of the other anchor elements.

Answer (score 2):

Updated your [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/5csofnhz/5/)

What I have added is:

1. One variable to store current selected link
2. Check it with the hovered link
3. If it is not the same then perform Background change
4. Else do nothing.
5. Update everytime any link(One or Two) is hovered

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer and interesting approach Puneet. It seems i'm able to do the same thing, but with less code using Manik's suggestion above. Is there any particular reason why this approach may be more beneficial? Thanks alot!

Comment: @OliverChalmers - No particular reasons. Every 100th developer will have a different approach to do one thing. Even at first I had tried to use your homeNavOff function, but latter I tried this current approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
Look on this :
    http://jsfiddle.net/5csofnhz/6/
```

If any query feel free to ask